# Can't create secrets in kubernetes with terraform cloud

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-cloud

I am trying to create a secret within my kubernetes cluster and terraform cloud.
I can create the cluster with no problems, but problems arise when I try to inject a secret in the cluster. 
Here is a simplified version of my terraform manifest:

```
terraform {
  backend "remote" {
    organization = "my-org"

    // Workspaces separate deployment envs (like prod, stage, or UK, Italy)
    workspaces {
      name = "my-workspace-name"
    }
  }
}
resource "google_container_cluster" "demo-k8s-cluster" {
  name = "demo-cluster"
  location = var.region
  initial_node_count = 1
  project = var.project-id


  master_auth {
    username = ""
    password = ""

    client_certificate_config {
      issue_client_certificate = false
    }
  }

  node_config {
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
    ]

//    service_account = var.service-account

    metadata = {
      disable-legacy-endpoints = "true"
    }
  }

  timeouts {
    create = "30m"
    update = "40m"
  }
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host     = google_container_cluster.demo-k8s-cluster.endpoint
  username = google_container_cluster.demo-k8s-cluster.master_auth.0.username
  password = google_container_cluster.demo-k8s-cluster.master_auth.0.password
  client_certificate     = base64decode(google_container_cluster.demo-k8s-cluster.master_auth.0.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(google_container_cluster.demo-k8s-cluster.master_auth.0.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(google_container_cluster.demo-k8s-cluster.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
  load_config_file = "false"
}

resource "kubernetes_secret" "cloudsql-db-credentials" {
   metadata {
       name = "cloudsql-instance-credentials-test"
   }

  data = {
    "stack-creds.json" = var.service-account
  }

}
```

The plan works fine, I get the following error at `Apply` stage:

```
Error: secrets is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "default"

  on infrastructure.tf line 149, in resource "kubernetes_secret" "cloudsql-db-credentials":
 149: resource "kubernetes_secret" "cloudsql-db-credentials" {
```

Comment: It looks like problem with user [authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/). Could you share any details about your `.kube/config` ? Can you run manually `kubectl apply -f secret.yaml` from the node on which you run **terraform** ? What is the result ?

Comment: Please also review [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/index.html#authentication) section.

Comment: I don't think is a problem with the kubernetes auth config because I can manually create the secret from command line with no problem. The issue is that I can't get it working with terraform cloud.

Comment: By "problem with the user authentication" I don't  necessarily mean there is something wrong with your `.kube/config`. Note, that when running commands directly you are not connecting to kubernetes api as user `system:anonymous`. But when you connect to it through terraform cloud, the API server for some reason recognizes you as "system:anonymous" user, which is not authorized to perform the desired operation on your kubernetes cluster.

Comment: It looks like authentication can be also handled by simply providing [`config_path`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/index.html#config_path) so **terraform** can use the data already present in your `kubeconfig` file when connecting to your **kubernetes cluster**.

Answer (score 0):

As per @mario comment, it turns out terraform cloud can't get the right identity and can't connect to the cluster to inject the secret. Instead of using terraform cloud I have instead opted to use GCS backend and managed to get it working. The following configuration works:

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "infrastructure-state-bucket"
    prefix = "test/so_simple2"
  }
}

// The project-id variable contains project id to use.
variable "project-id" {
  type = string
}

variable "region" {
  type = string
}

variable "cluster-name" {
  type = string
}

provider "google" {
  project = var.project-id
  region = var.region
}

provider "random" {}

resource "random_id" "id" {
  byte_length = 4
  prefix      = "${var.cluster-name}-"
}


resource "google_container_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = random_id.id.hex
  location = var.region
  initial_node_count = 1
  project = var.project-id
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host     = google_container_cluster.cluster.endpoint
  username = google_container_cluster.cluster.master_auth.0.username
  password = google_container_cluster.cluster.master_auth.0.password
  client_certificate     = base64decode(google_container_cluster.cluster.master_auth.0.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(google_container_cluster.cluster.master_auth.0.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(google_container_cluster.cluster.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
// This is a deal breaker, if is set to false I get same error.
//  load_config_file = "false"
}

resource "kubernetes_secret" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "basic-auth"
  }

  data = {
    username = "admin"
    password = "P4ssw0rd"
  }

  type = "kubernetes.io/basic-auth"
}
```